# OpenSSL-iOS swift : Getting PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey nil

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, openssl

I am using Openssl library in ios swift and want to decrypt the encrypted private key using @srsa supplied. Here srsa is passphrase. PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey getting nil here. Please check below code snippet.

```
"encrypted_private_key" : "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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\r\nNO9XbQrKd3VsrvPEE9YqyQAsHQ==\r\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"

"srsa" = "x8SBIvL/L0h3GUsVtYz8Mk69KwEe9ibZxw62UT0Vy5k4"

let beginning = "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"
                        let tail = "-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"
                        let certificateString = encrypted_private_key.replacingOccurrences(of: beginning, with: "")
                                                           .replacingOccurrences(of: tail, with: "")
                                                           .replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
                                                           .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
                                                            .replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "")

guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: certificateString!) else {
print("Unable to cast string to data")
    return nil }

let boi = BIO_new_mem_buf(data.bytes, Int32(data.count))
let passPhrase = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: (self.srsa as NSString).utf8String
let privateKey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(boi, nil, nil, passPhrase)
```

getting privateKey nil here...Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are at least two things wrong with the base64 encoded private key. The software that wrote the PEM key was probably Windows based. 1) The string was **escaped** which means certain characters are replaced. Example **/** with **\/**. 2) Line endings are in DOS format (CR-LF) instead of Unix (LF). Both problems are a symptom of the software that created the PEM data which is incorrect. The code in this question is removing the PEM headers which are also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The key you've pasted hasn't been parsed properly, you missed the occurrences of `\/` which is an escaped `/` character.

This is your key after the replacements you make:

```
MIIFHzBJBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wPDAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIysWhJMC\/TvkCAggA
MB0GCWCGSAFlAwQBKgQQgttwCnv0IFah3\/+zjXLYIQSCBNAtaLd4WOtNgQoI3Xpz
KAQfdBrh0V25lRoaFZJ6BLD4UqD62zTT1TlGko9\/XG5XAuONjwr9YOL0VWcdDyeD
ASzgUrmd5QN3mMuiVPld2rb2RSvgWSxUKA6yWguZTA2lh7hwFyVz4igjJ5zMlph7
2cdbodDrTf+0K9orgRn3BV3UJyY70JZIr9Uj9DRfiBW8MByA6ChgEt25YrbOImol
EVKQ1JoOxAI89EMpfKrN8h2ujf63674cviA5KxYwRaAdMVGr+C9ipMC\/mk17THQl
Fj2+pYJRHdWl0vH72tAVsuYlDHNI55Yqg2+H6ZlStdlG0rybWAkCNIIwWsj86fo3
\/i\/rDi\/CFXhcHT2MpaznbPOoPn85nYGfHZHRlQUM61Ipp+Vg8ftI4ekI\/dWiPjMv
h2MRCa9pVJ4hjIkS3Z\/7yEzRzA1Xj+qckJeFYstZXaAOvh80QxjE2bAn16F9AWCW
MFHxH\/Y3XPBci\/kfwg4qYLQKVplnlRtPknqV+1JDj+1OPBWgjYeuWNzgxc4mJs0H
+UeCMvFgDEUDZXMC+KsK7OCav2eTP9sjdkvjOT7RY0BIxaO9hqgilYcVPBtqRQPO
7ctJIfzUOo\/7abQpGillMTGXOIue1dEnXuoYCEPpEtxzKrQSGE8ORqxZogYaIuyI
HC82fAlr9Aoo1dnBw3H2cdt56RnmZsASoj8\/ZsNrcgaldBlyM4ImKt9vd28neNdy
2jVVWjlXZYFTunpPhJrIHO2TeC9szg3cZ3NLZhP5nEz6WOsd1n5jify4LR2ici2e
sUFWfPE1JtOXy4Yd1C5+mtg7I1bkROzZOxYC69aQBygggtp1nXavuq4ECrKk\/gj7
OsLkC0Jh91cj45lYwnt9SO8lSVwpFspQCwalG7cAyLVD3jeLH5nbs3fEP3BXE8in
tSgTXFjbwyBD6nJ0cxKYMQ+yzr9dDQI55n1mKdyFgEWMBD2MWTEdXCBzreXBcYWD
gDRarxKbQaWd9ANCT1Us1nBc08OvxQiLIo8dhDd\/qcIx+kWS+o1Uxc0eY9HRYhX+
YPmA0Jzf6dCxHPc+1+ib\/wIGlhgA1xc\/HkILy7k\/Q5c7s5ogDuyNeFfncjlmidaW
PqhHN+EhqIbmPbogiewXUovZ6OmSmAkG4x4ZO6qn9myWtSEwz70bDrKIA2sJWK\/k
FccmW5l5dHmSPKc7fLnA6U0wRgUoE\/iiE7gl5ROjEevM\/G9AZhjdiL+6\/U8yYOwF
tbB87qQUvI27UtSWoEE0LdVcmUDKlJN7Gw+Vkk\/szueKFYCVBlJVcba0TrLYUq6H
nQttGvyWKqysI\/JHvd2QcHywufF90I0WYBCZ+JnHBchKfZNcfIFv38GemfeOwWu5
adK+ivkHOjq3Q\/WLCcegjvE5\/ZqkG8RVZVZJ\/4oH1bQPP5nVP7FJ7cMSx1ZszkD8
uhc3FltRpS5238otTnO0WNbwmNbVYe\/j6on4bvrzlzKq3CTe0Tn0HA31DXt7Rw2y
IINtnOjgUQZRhsfdMT3NDsmhRgxFbmda4nmBatRqWt1WPKz8rwio3WWzFiOgE8DV
Ltx+DF9h7EpowL4IA3eusOtrOProizjyFZVvgsLbwFBNMckvmiwcq\/V6iaN52ZxX
NO9XbQrKd3VsrvPEE9YqyQAsHQ==
```

Notice the uneven padding, which is due to uneven line length, which should always be 64 characters. This is the fixed key:

```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```

P.S. I hope this private key isn't the one you plan on using in production or for any security since you willingly gave away the password.

Comment: I have updated the encrypted_key in the post. There was something print copy mistake.

Comment: Well did you check with  the updated key as well? I'm not here to debug stuff for you, try printing out the key and check if it's in the right format, that was the obvious mistake you made initially.

Comment: Yep, I have checked the key, still getting same issue..